# Configure library for tomahawk in JSF 2.0

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, tomahawk

I am trying to upload a file using `<t:inputFileUpload/>` , in JSF2.0 facelets

for that i need to use namespace **xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apche.org/tomahawk/"**

but showing error like **"No library found for this namespace"**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"     
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" <!--Error Here : No library found for this namespace--->
```

> 

In above code last line show's error

How could i manage this error...

Answer (score 0):

No library found for this namespace means you have not added library 
Add tomahawk-1.1.9.jar to your Build Path